# How to know which package is the one responsible for installing a given program

Tags: linux, search, yum, package-management, packages

MEGA summary: How to search for programs easier when there is no access to GUI internet browser, I have no phone on me etc. Just having CLI in linux.

Let's say I'm using CentOS 7 and I'm looking for a program to install. I want to install "locate" command. To do it I write `yum search locate`. The shell answers with a list of packages.

```
mlocate.x86_64 : An utility for finding files by name
perl-File-ShareDir.noarch : Locate per-dist and per-module shared files
which.x86_64 : Displays where a particular program in your path is located
```

In this case I intuitively know that the mlocate.x86_64 is probably what I'm looking for, so I install it by `yum install mlocate.x86_64` but I have an enormous trouble doing that with programs that when searched for are being given to me as a giant list of packages. For example: I install minimal installation centos 7. After doing that i search for a dekstop environment xfce `yum search xfce`. The output is massive and I don't know what even are these packages. I do know that xfce is a "desktop environment" so I `yum search xfce | grep dekstop`. That gives me:

```
libxfce4util.i686 : Utility library for the Xfce4 desktop environment
libxfce4util.x86_64 : Utility library for the Xfce4 desktop environment
xfce4-power-manager.x86_64 : Power management for the Xfce desktop environment
exo.i686 : Application library for the Xfce desktop environment
exo.x86_64 : Application library for the Xfce desktop environment
xfdesktop.x86_64 : Desktop manager for the XFce Desktop Environment
```

The only thing that comes close to what I think I want is:

```
xfdesktop.x86_64 : Desktop manager for the XFce Desktop Environment
```

However I am not certain. Nowhere does it say "Xfce desktop environment". It just says that it's a Desktop manager for that environment. I don't know what that means. Maybe that particular example just shows that I'm stupid but I'm having this problem with many programs that I want to install.

I search for an ssh client:

```
[root@box-codeanywhere /]# yum search ssh | grep client
gsi-openssh-clients.x86_64 : SSH client applications with GSI authentication
libguac-client-ssh.i686 : SSH support for guacd
libguac-client-ssh.x86_64 : SSH support for guacd
ne7ssh.i686 : SSH Library is a Secure Shell client software written in C++
ne7ssh.x86_64 : SSH Library is a Secure Shell client software written in C++
openssh-clients.x86_64 : An open source SSH client applications
perl-Net-OpenSSH.noarch : Perl SSH client package implemented on top of OpenSSH
perl-Net-SSH-Perl.noarch : SSH (Secure Shell) client
dropbear.x86_64 : SSH2 server and client
perl-Net-SFTP-Foreign.noarch : SSH File Transfer Protocol client
putty.x86_64 : SSH, Telnet and Rlogin client
                            : clients and server
```

How do I know which package I need to install... I'm having this problem extremely often. It looks like I need to know the exact name string of a package responsible for installing certain program. My question is: How to search for program easier when there is no access to GUI internet browser, I have no phone on me etc. Just having CLI in linux.

Comment: There are several [command line browsers for Linux](https://opensource.com/article/16/12/web-browsers-linux-command-line)

Comment: Sorry for not being precise. I want to find out if there is a way to achieve my goal without any browser.

Answer (score 1):

Your tool for searching for a program is apt-file, which you install this way :

```
# Install apt-file, which allows you to search
# for the package containing a file
sudo apt-get install apt-file

# Update the package/file mapping database
sudo apt-file update
```

If you know the absolute path for the program, you may search for it :

```
$ apt-file search /usr/bin/locate
```

Or you may search for the program appearing in the path :

```
# Search for "locate" at the end of a path
apt-file search --regexp '/locate$'
```

In the output only one package will specify an executable located in your standard
PATH, which gives a clue that it might be the right one.

You can also find out more about the package to ensure that it seems like the right one:

```
$ apt-cache show <package-name>
```

This will list all the programs included in the package and can serve as verification.

Yum also accepts the command `whatprovides` (or `provides`) to search for installed or not installed binaries:

```
yum whatprovides <path-to-file>
```

zypper's search command can check file lists when used with the -f option :

```
zypper se -f /usr/bin/locate
```

Pkgfile, available as pkgtools for pacman based systems, provides a similar search
feature like the others above:

```
pkgfile -si /usr/bin/mysqldump
```

Fore more information see :

- [How to find out which (not installed) Debian package a file belongs to?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/how-to-find-out-which-not-installed-debian-package-a-file-belongs-to)
- [How can I find the package that contains a program in Debian? [duplicate]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191977/how-can-i-find-the-package-that-contains-a-program-in-debian)